# How to Create a framework which includes UIControls and their actions?

Tags: ios

I need to create a framework using an existing iOS project. That project contains UIControls and their actions.I need to include them as well?.

I have created a project and made it as a framework and embedded it's NIB file in that framework itself.Then I have created another project and added that framework to it.Now I can retrieve the same NIB file, and I have populated that as UI.But while I try to trigger a button(this button outlet and its action are written in framework compile source) action on that NIB it says that button is unrecognized.So I think the NIB(view) and implementation file(controller) are not linked inside a framework as they usually  link inside a Xcode project.Please let me know your inferences or the facts you know.

Comment: Did you find anything??